# segfault caused by a call to spdlog::get( "logger" )->info() in a file_event_handlers's callback

Tags: c++, logging, gcc, segmentation-fault, spdlog

The below program crashes due to a seg fault. I don't find a reason for this. All I know at the moment is that the two calls to `info()` member `spdlog::get( "basic_logger" )->info( "\nLogging started..." );` and `spdlog::get( "basic_logger" )->info( "Logging finished." );` are causing problems (the first one causes a segfault and the second one causes a double free).

A minimal example:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <exception>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <fmt/chrono.h>
#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>
#include <spdlog/sinks/basic_file_sink.h>


int main( )
{
    spdlog::file_event_handlers handlers;

    handlers.after_open   = [ ]( const spdlog::filename_t filename, std::FILE* const stream )
                            {   // Comment this line out to see the error caused by the before_close callback
                                spdlog::get( "basic_logger" )->info( "\nLogging started..." );
                                fmt::print( stream, "\n[{}] [{}] Logging started...\n",
                                            std::chrono::system_clock::now( ), filename );
                            };

    handlers.before_close = [ ]( const spdlog::filename_t filename, std::FILE* const stream )
                            {
                                spdlog::get( "basic_logger" )->info( "Logging finished." );
                                fmt::print( stream, "[{}] [{}] Logging finished.\n",
                                            std::chrono::system_clock::now( ), filename );
                            };

    try
    {
        auto logger { spdlog::basic_logger_st( "basic_logger", "logs/basic-log.txt", true, handlers ) };
    }
    catch ( const std::exception& sx )
    {
        fmt::print( stderr, "\nSomething went wrong during program startup: log file init failed: {}\n\n",
                            sx.what( ) );
    }
}
```

The errors:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

And also:

```
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Build command:

```
g++ -std=c++23 -O3 -march=westmere -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wshadow -fwhole-program -DNDEBUG `pkg-config --cflags spdlog` `pkg-config --libs spdlog` Temp.cpp -o runTemp
```

The calls to `print` are not causing any issues though. However, I want to replace them with calls to `info()` as seen above because that logs more details.

Comment: Please run your code under a debugger and edit your question with a stack trace

Comment: @Botje I have looked at that before. The `spdlog::get( "basic_logger" )` function call returns a `nullptr` in the first callback and dereferencing it causes the seg fault that I mentioned. And the same call in the second callback causes a call to `operator delete(void*)` which ends as a double-free error. I just don't know how to avoid using this function in these callbacks. I'm looking for a replacement that formats the log message similarly to `get("logger")->info()`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not possible, unfortunately. Your call to `spdlog::basic_logger_st` ends up [here](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/57a9fd0841f00e92b478a07fef62636d7be612a8/include/spdlog/details/synchronous_factory.h):

```
    static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> create(std::string logger_name, SinkArgs &&... args)
    {
/*[1]*/ auto sink = std::make_shared<Sink>(std::forward<SinkArgs>(args)...);
        auto new_logger = std::make_shared<spdlog::logger>(std::move(logger_name), std::move(sink));
/*[2]*/ details::registry::instance().initialize_logger(new_logger);
        return new_logger;
    }
```

The line marked with `[1]` is the one that creates the sink and calls your `after_open` callback, but line `[2]` is actually the one that makes the logger available as `basic_logger`.

You will have to hoist the log statement in `after_open` to the line after your call to `basic_logger_st`. The log statement in `before_close` should work without a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the details. But "*The log statement in before_close*" does not work. It makes the program crash.

Comment: I guess it's because the `get` function creates and returns a `shared_ptr` that calls delete upon its destruction while delete had already been called before.